# Spring / Spring Tool Suite: how disable a warn log category

Tags: spring

I need to disable the warn log category for `org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer`

I'm using STS version 4. How and where I need to act in preferences?

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29612

Answer (score 1):

We can set logging level in application.propertirs file using ‘logging.level.*=LEVEL’ where ‘LEVEL’ is one of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF. The root logger can be configured using logging.level.root.

Example application.properties:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

[reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add line

`logging.level.org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer=OFF`
into your application properites file.

It worked for me now.